# Is a body of water "die See", "das Meer" or "der Ozean"?

Tags: meaning, difference

Oceans and seas are sometimes "Seen", sometimes "Meere" and sometimes "Ozeane". E.g:

- Das Mittelmeer
- Karibisches Meer
- Die Nordsee
- Atlantischer Ozean

Some belong to two groups, e.g. "die Ostsee"/"Baltisches Meer". Is the difference between the words purely etymological, or is there a difference in meaning? If so, is it merely oceanographic, or do laypeople know the difference?

Comment: Es gibt auch ein Nordmeer, nördlich von Norwegen :)

Comment: "Baltisches Meer" is a very uncommon word in German. People would actually have some trouble to understand you if you used this, especially as "Baltikum/baltische Staaten" is used as an umbrella term for Estonia, Latvia and Lithuania. To cover all states that border on the Baltic Sea, use the term "Ostsee-Anrainerstaaten".

Comment: Also note that most people will just say "Karibik" instead of "Karibisches Meer". (Don't say there's a difference between these two - most people won't care `:-)`)

Comment: For more confusion: "Steinhuder Meer" - is a **lake**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the usage is loosely coupled to the size of the water body, with Ozean being the largest, Meer coming second, and then See*. For some contradictions of the definitions I give here (and that's why it's only "loosely coupled"), also consult [Gigili's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1563/is-a-body-of-water-die-see-das-meer-or-der-ozean/1576#1576).

There are very few **oceans** ([Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozean) lists five of them) and their group is closed, i.e. there's little discussion about what else could be an ocean.

[**Meer**](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meer) can be used to describe almost any saltwater body that is not a lake. Unfortunately, some saltwater lakes are bearing names with "Meer" in them, such as the "Kaspisches Meer" (Caspian Sea) or the "Totes Meer" (Dead Sea). To add to the general confusion, "Meer" also [means "lake"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meer_(Begriffskl%C3%A4rung)) in Low German and Dutch, so there are some (a few) freshwater Meere such as the "Steinhuder Meer" or "Zwischenahner Meer". To most non-locals though, those names sound similarly strange as to non-native speakers.

For **See***, there are [two meanings](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/See_(Begriffskl%C3%A4rung)): "Meer im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch" and "Nebenmeer - einen durch Inselketten o.ä. abgegrenzten Randbereich eines Meeres", which doesn't help with the aforementioned confusion :-)

Concerning the difference between See* and Meer, I think most people don't bother, they just go with the main name for the water body in question and don't take offense if it's called the other way. Conversations like this are perfectly normal:

> A: Wir fahren im Sommer ans Meer.
>
> B: Wohin geht's?
>
> A: An die Ostsee.

Personally, I would expect Meer to be larger than See* and wouldn't call the Mediterranean Sea(Mittelmeer) or the Pacific ocean (Pazifik) a See*, but that's just a gut feeling.

*female version: if it's not a lake, always use the female article: **die See**. See [Hendrik's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1563/is-a-body-of-water-die-see-das-meer-or-der-ozean/1577#1577) for more details on the gender of See.

Comment: Regarding "always female", "der Alpsee" is close to here.

Comment: @Tim yes, but that's a lake :-)

Comment: @Jan, re your last edit: The _Kaspisches Meer_ and the _Totes Meer_ are saltwater bodies that are lakes `:-)` But the _Großer Salzsee_ is also a lake and carries _See_ in its name ...

Comment: @Hendrik: oh boy, what a mess :-) "Großer Salzsee" is not a problem, since it's "der See", not "die See". Completely different topic there ;-) "Kaspisches Meer" and "Totes Meer" are exceptions as per Gigili's answer, although I could make this a bit clearer...

Comment: @Jan: I just wonder, does the salt contribute to them being _Meere?_

Comment: @Hendrik: In the times where those water bodies were named, people didn't have the complete overview of the world as we have now with satellite maps and such. I think they just assumed since it's salty, it's similar to that other big salty water body, so they called it the same. I can imagine that it took mankind some centuries to figure out that the Caspian Sea really is a saltwater lake with no connection to the world's seas (anymore).

Comment: It's worth noting that "die See" also has a more poetic aspect, as long as it is not used for a fixed term like "Nordsee". This is partially because the word has aged and is not frequently used in modern language - except maybe in northern Germany.

Comment: The answer is correct. I just want to mention one exception I know: Das "Steinhuder Meer" is in fact a lake (it has no saltwater) (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhuder_Meer) "Meer" is used more or less metaphorically here. But this is clearly an exception to the rules Jan describes.

Answer (score 7):

Let me expand on the gender of "See" that Jan already mentioned. It's very important not to confuse *der See* (the lake) and *die See* (the sea). One thing you can be sure about: if you hear *der See*, then always a lake without connection to the sea is meant. On the other hand, some lakes do carry the name *Meer*, which Jan explained etymologically.

Confusion can also be caused by the synonymous usage of *die See* and *das Meer*. You can say both

> Wir fahren im Sommer ans Meer.

and

> Wir fahren im Sommer an die See.

Both are perfectly OK and mean the same.

Finally let me mention that another word for *Ozean* is *Weltmeer*.

Comment: I know that this answers the question only tangentially. Please let me know if you think it's too tangential.

Comment: It's definitely useful information (and too long for a comment).

Answer (score 3):

About the difference:

- It doesn't have anything to do with "size" , contradiction:

> Das Meer, das zwischen der Balkanhalbinsel und Kleinasien liegt, misst dagegen nur 11 500 Quadratkilometer und käme damit auf der Rangliste hinter den größten Seen erst auf Platz 18.

- It doesn't have anything to do with "salty water", contradiction:

> Der Salar de Uyuni in Bolivien beispielsweise ist mit 12 000 Quadratkilometern der größte Salzsee der Welt. Er enthält etwa 10 Milliarden Tonnen Salz.

- **Meer**  is open to exchange water, but **Seen** are usually an
  uncorrupted inland water.

I think there's no special differences in their meaning that you can categorize them plus that sea is commonly used as a synonym for ocean. actually, most of them has the word "see" or "meer" in their name:

[image]

An exception:

> Das Kaspische Meer, Überrest des einstmaligen Weltmeeres Tethys, ist somit eigentlich ein See.

Comment: Both Nordsee and Ostsee exchange a lot of water with the Atlantic.

Comment: @Tim N: As I said, "usually" plus that "ostsee" is also called "Baltisches **Meer** ".

Comment: @Gigili: As Jan has already pointed out, hardly anyone will understand that your talking about the _Ostsee_ if you say _Baltisches Meer_. And don't forget "Zwischenahner Meer" and others in northern Germany!

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: like "Kaspische Meer" which has meer in the name but it's a "See", "[Ostsee](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostsee)" and "[Nordsee](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordsee)" are **Meer** .

Comment: @Gigili: Right, I just wanted to point out that there are more exceptions.

Comment: @Gigili: thanks, I have edited my answer accordingly and linked to your contradictions as well. I think we can agree on the fact that there are lakes (**der** See) that are bigger than some seas (**die** See), but in my eyes, that shouldn't contradict the perceived relative size of a body of water called "**die** ...-See" vs. one called "das ...-Meer", or does it?

Comment: -1 Since the question ist not about "der See" (the lake) vs. "das Meer", but about "die See" vs. "das Meer"

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific difference between *ans Meer* and *an die See*. They both mean the sea. And as hendrik also warned please do not get confused between an **die** See (sea) and an **den** See (lake). There is nothing more to be confused of. As both of them can be used for sea only, you will have to frame the sentences accordingly.